# DateChooser updating correctly only if visible at start

Tags: apache-flex, halo

I'm writing a Flex application and I came across what I think is a weird problem.

I want to create a text box and a DateChooser as the datefield didn't do what I wanted and it's Halo so I can't skin it easily. I want the DateChooser to show when I click on the text input. Here is an except from my code:

```
    <s:TextInput id="wholeDate" width="100"  
                 mouseOver="stopChangeToNormal();"
                 paddingRight="10"
                 click="date1.visible = true"
                 focusOut="date1.visible = false"/>
    <s:Button label="Go" width="70" />
</s:Panel>

<mx:DateChooser id="date1" 
                visible = "false"
                change="useDate(event);" 
                mouseOver="changeToNormalState = false;" 
                y="{wholeDate.y + buttonsGroup.y + 20}"
                x="{wholeDate.x + buttonsGroup.x - 175 }" />
```

The weird thing is that it works if I make it `visible = "true"` to start, but if I have it `visible="false"` it doesn't work! It shows, but the date I select doesn't show in the box as it does if I have it as `visible="true"`, but I don't want it to be visible initially.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its actually anything to do with the initial visibility of the DateChooser. Have you verified that your event handlers are indeed called, and in an order that makes sense? The problem appears to be that when you attempt to make a selection in the DateChooser, the TextInput gets a focusOut event, which hides the DateChooser, which apparently prevents it from receiving the selection event. I think you need to be more selective about when you actually hide the DateChooser. Perhaps you need to defer the hiding so it has a chance to respond to the selection first.

Comment: You are right again lach! it was the focusOut issue. I removed it from the TextInput and it worked. Yes the event wasn't being called at all. Thank you very much